# Coordinating flow of events in Vue.Js from child A to parent, and from parent to child B

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

Working with VUE.JS...

Having a '*theParent*' component with two childs: '*theForm*' and '*theButtons*'.
(This is a simplification of more complex scenario).

In '*theButtons*' exists a '*Clear*' button to clean fields of '*theForm*' form.

I am able to pass the event from '*theButtons*' to '*theParent*', but not from '*theParent*' to '*theForm*'  ¿?

Within '**theButtons**':

```
<b-button v-on:click="clean()">Clear</b-button>

methods: {
    clean() {
        this.$emit('clean');
    }
},
```

Within '**theParent**':

```
<theForm />

<theButtons v-on:clean="clean"/>

methods: {
    clean() {       
        this.$emit('theForm.clean'); //Here is the point I dont know what to put
    }
},
```

Within '**theForm**':

```
methods: {
    clean() {       
        alert("This is what I want to get executed!!");
    }
},
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a [ref](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-edge-cases.html#Accessing-Child-Component-Instances-amp-Child-Elements) to the `TheForm` component then run its method from parent :

```
<theForm  ref="form" />

<theButtons v-on:clean="clean"/>

methods: {
    clean() {       
        this.$refs.form.clean(); //clean should be a method in theForm component.
    }
},
```

Or you could add a prop to `theForm` component which could be updated in parent and watch in child component to clean the form :

```
<theForm :clean="clean" />

<theButtons v-on:clean="clean"/>

data(){
  return {
     clean:false
  }
},
methods: {
    clean() {       
        this.clean=clean;
    }
},
```

inside `theForm` :

```
props:['clean'],
watch:{
   clean(val){
      if(val){
           this.clean()
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. (I am going to use option 1)

Answer (score 1):

One thing to keep in mind is the flow of passing data from child to parent and vice versa.
In a nutshell:

1. Parent => Child: if you want to pass data from parent to child, use props.
2. Child => Parent: if you want to pass data from child to parent, use events.

One solution to your problem is to have `<b-button>` as a child to the `<theForm>` as follows:

```
<theForm v-on:clean="cleanForm">
 <!-- form children -->
 ....
 <theButton />
 ....
</theForm>
```

Another solution is to have an event bus that passes events between components which is totally unnecessary in your case.

Reference: https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/component-basics.html#passing-data-to-child-components-with-props
https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/component-basics.html#listening-to-child-components-events